# Is there a name "-phobia" for fear of tape? For example duct tape, tesa film and stickers

Tags: terminology

I heard there are people who are afraid of tape, such as duct tape, tesa film and stickers.

I tried to find the name of the symptom, but I couldn't find it.
Is there a medical term for it, like "-phobia"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pittakionophobia](http://www.peterfieldhypnotherapy.co.uk/fear-of-stickers-afraid-of-labels-stickers-phobia.html) = fear of stickers and sticky labels

Clinical phobias are usually named after the Greek words for things.  A more direct Greek translation of the English word “tape” is *ταινία*, but [taeniophobia](http://common-phobias.com/taenio/phobia.htm) refers to the fear of tape*worms*.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I have Pittakionophobia it sucks and people think it's not a real phobia but put anything sticky on me then I start to freak out